# Running ruby script on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, github

I've downloaded clone of the [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) repository from GitHub and installed ruby using [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and I want to be able to run the sample, but I might have missed something since even the tests are not running.

here is the line I want to run

```
Linguist::FileBlob.new("lib/linguist.rb").language.name #=> "Ruby"
```

**Here is the content of the library:**

[image]

**Here is the tests folder:**

[image]

When I try to run the `test_blob.rb` file from the tests folder, I get the following error:

[image]

> Cannot load such a file

Comment: try Linguist::FileBlob.new("../lib/linguist.rb").language.name

Comment: also run the file from linguist\test folder.

Comment: I've tried running the test script from that folder and I got the same error.

Comment: You mean I should create a file at the test folder with that line of code and run it? I've tried it and it fails - "Uninitialized constant Linguist (NameError)"

Comment: Problem with your path? It's a `require...` error, so it's telling you it can't find the file `linguist/file_blob`. Note that is not an absolute path. So first off, did you do a `bundle install` where the Gemfile is in the repo you cloned? Can you show your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Did you read and follow the **Installation** section: https://github.com/github/linguist ?

Comment: I haven't used bundle install since it doesn't work for some reason or I misused it. I've installed the bundler but there is no bundle.exe file, only the bundler.exe. the bundle install doesn't work from the command line.

Comment: had you try `bundle exec rake test` before running the manual test execution?